# IOException в Java при попытке создания потока записи в файл

Tags: java, файлы, filestream

Задаю в командной строке имя файла для записи в него. Объект `File f = new File("D:\test")` создаётся нормально (файл изначально не существует), однако когда я пытаюсь получить поток для записи:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Вылетает `IOException` с сообщением (среда Eclipse): `Failed to open D:\test. Error message: Присоединенное к системе устройство не работает.` Причём если я поменяю имя файла на, к примеру, `D:\test.txt` (т.е. поставлю **любое** расширение), то всё работает нормально. Почему так?

UPD[26.08.2015]: Ёлки-палки. Дико извиняюсь, я неправильно понял причину ошибки. `FileOutputStream` работает нормально, всё дело было в попытке открытия файла методом `jawa.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`. Для файлов без расширения нет приложения по-умолчанию.

Comment: Это ошибка операционной системы. Если Вы все еще на ХР, попробуйте на "семерке".

Comment: Мне вот просто интересно, какой файл вы пытаетесь создать без расширения? Правильно вам эклипс говорит.

Comment: @ГенераторКачества: что страшного в файле без расширения? У меня на рабочей машине довольно много файлов без расширения, взять хотя бы тот же `/dev/null`

Comment: Автор, не могли бы вы выложить цельный кусок кода, чтобы можно было быстро воспроизвести эту же ситуацию у себя?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: хотя бы то, что нужно посмотреть, что передаётся в конструктор `File()`. Указывая имя файла без расширения, топикстартер говорит джаве, что возьми на диске `D:` в каталоге `/test` "сам не знаю что". Джава думает, что это каталог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дико извиняюсь, я неправильно понял причину ошибки. `FileOutputStream` работает нормально, всё дело было в попытке открытия файла методом `jawa.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`. Для файлов без расширения нет приложения по-умолчанию.